# Custom Gutenberg block problem - This block has encountered an error and cannot be previewed

Tags: custom-post-types, block-editor

I have a problem with my Gutenberg custom block.
Alone, it works perfectly on every page or post.
But, when I want to add this block, which is set to be dynamic, to a custom post type, it says "This block has encountered an error and cannot be previewed.". What can be a problem to do this?
Code is given here. Thank you in advance.

**plugin.php - *defining Gutenberg custom block***

```
function movieFavQuote() {
  wp_enqueue_script(
    'favquote-handler',
    plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'quote-block.js',
    array('wp-blocks', 'wp-i18n', 'wp-editor'),
    true
  );
}
 
add_action('enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'movieFavQuote');

function favQuoteMeta() {
  register_meta('post', 'content', array('show_in_rest' => true, 'type' => 'string', 'single' => true));
}

add_action('init', 'favQuoteMeta');
```

**quote-block.js - *defining Gutenberg custom block***

```
wp.blocks.registerBlockType('pavle/movie-quote', {
    title: 'Favourite movie quote',
    icon: "smiley",
    category: "common",
    attributes: {
        content: {type: 'string', source: 'meta', meta: 'content'}
    },

    edit: function(props) {
        function updateContent(event) {
        props.setAttributes({content: event.target.value})
        }

        return wp.element.createElement(
            "div",
            null,
            wp.element.createElement("h3", null, " Favourite movie quote: "),
            wp.element.createElement("input", {
              type: "text",
              value: props.attributes.content,
              onChange: updateContent
            })
          );
    },
    save: function(props) {
        return wp.element.createElement("h2", null, " Favourite movie quote:", props.attributes.content);
    }
})
```

**movies.php - *custom post type defining***

```
<?php

    function movie_cpt() {
    
            $labels = array(
    'name'                  => _x( 'Movies', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'         => _x( 'Movie', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'             => __( 'Movies', 'text_domain' ),
    'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Movies', 'text_domain' ),
    'archives'              => __( 'Movie Archive', 'text_domain' ),
    'attributes'            => __( 'Item Attributes', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'             => __( 'All Movies', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Movie', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new'               => __( 'Add New Movie', 'text_domain' ),
    'new_item'              => __( 'New Movie', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Movie', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'           => __( 'Update Movie', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'             => __( 'View Movie', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_items'            => __( 'View Movie', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'          => __( 'Search Movies', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'             => __( 'Movie not Found', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Movie not Found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
    'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
    'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'text_domain' ),
    'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list'            => __( 'Movie List', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
    'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
);
$args = array(
    'label'                 => __( 'Movie', 'text_domain' ),
    'description'           => __( 'Post Type Description', 'text_domain' ),
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor'),
    'taxonomies'            => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
    'hierarchical'          => false,
    'public'                => true,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_in_menu'          => true,
    'menu_position'         => 5,
    'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
    'can_export'            => true,
    'has_archive'           => true,
    'exclude_from_search'   => false,
    'publicly_queryable'    => true,
    'capability_type'       => 'page',
    'show_in_rest'          => true,
    'register_meta_box_cb'  => 'movie_meta_box'
);
        register_post_type( 'movie', $args );
    
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'movie_cpt');
        
    function movie_meta_box() {
            add_meta_box(
                'movie-title',
                __('Movie Title', 'sitepoint'),
                'movie_title_meta_box_callback',
            );
    }
    
    add_action('add_meta_boxes_movie', 'movie_meta_box');
    
    function movie_title_meta_box_callback($post) {
        wp_nonce_field('movie_title_nonce', 'movie_title_nonce');
        $value = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_movie_title', true);
        echo '<textarea style = "width:100%" id="movie_title" name="movie_title">' . esc_attr( $value ) . '</textarea>';
    }
    function save_movie_title_meta_box_data($post_id) {
        if (!isset($_POST['movie_title_nonce'])) {
            return;
        }
        if(!wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['movie_title_nonce'], 'movie_title_nonce' )) {
            return;
        }
        if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
            return;
        }
        if(isset($_POST['post_type']) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
            if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
                return;
            }
        }
        else {
            if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
                return;
            }
        }
        if(!isset($_POST['movie_title'])) { 
            return; 
        }
        $my_data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['movie_title'] );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_movie_title', $my_data );
    }
    
    add_action('save_post', 'save_movie_title_meta_box_data');
```

Comment: What do you mean by "when I want to add this block, which is set to be dynamic, to a custom post type"? Can you please explain more?

Comment: @KrunalBhimajiyani When I open Add new page/post and want to add this gutenberg block, everything is ok, both on front and backend. When I tru to add this block to custom-post Movies, there is a message "This block has encountered an error and cannot be previewed." I don't know why on a normal post or page there is no problem, but in custom post type there is a problem.

Comment: It is working fine for custom post types too. I have tried in my local.

Comment: Then it must work on my local, too, but I really don't know the problem. Maybe to deactivate/activate the Movies plugin?
Edit: again not working.

Comment: Can you please add the labels and args of your post type?

Comment: @KrunalBhimajiyani Yes, they are added now in the post.

Comment: In `function favQuoteMeta()` do you perhaps need to add your CPT as the object type in `register_meta()` as an object subtype?  See: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_meta/#comment-2933